# Mysql? Sqlite? ... What kind of database is better to conect with Visual C++?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm developing a software,wich i need to conect database with **Visual C++** (VS2008). The problem is that when the software is finished i need to export all the project to another computers and i must to include all the files and the database.

What kind of database i need? *Mysql*? *Sqlite*? *ODBC*? ...?

Thanks.

Comment: [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC) isn't a database.

Comment: it depends of the kind of software, the volume of data, whether the db is local for an application or a db in a client/server architecture, if you prefer opensource, etc. please explain your target

Answer (score 0):

SQL Express is good choice - database is easy to export as it's just a single file.
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Note - I'm assuming this is some kind of demo application/coding assignment.

Note - also assuming non-mobile platform: SQL Express is good choice here as minimal changes required to refactor to use SQL Server if need be.

If the app is eventually going to be on a mobile platform then SQL-Lite.

Comment: SQLLite databases can be saved to a single file, very much like the SQLCE `*.sdf` file.

Comment: Yeah - I double checked that as wasn't sure, and surprise surpise you can - so i edited answer already.